# Why doesn't android:clickable="false" work for Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

The following spinner is still clickable to show the list:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerFoo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false"/>
```

Could anyone shed some light on this?
I know from my reading that one can disable a spinner by doing it in Java code (spinnerFoo.setEnabled(false). My question is about doing it in XML.

**[EDIT]**
The following is all the Java code using the spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapterFoo = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, aiFoo);
spinnerFoo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFoo );
spinnerFoo .setAdapter(adapterFoo );
spinnerFoo .setSelection(1);
```

Comment: android:clickable="false" should work too. make sure you are not setting it true grammatically.

Comment: **use** `android:enabled="false"`

Comment: Those answers suggest what to do, but they don't really answer the question "why doesn't android:clickable=false work?" which is interesting.

Comment: look at my answer

Comment: @JunaidHafeez I added all the relevant Java code.

Answer (score 3):

Clickable is not going to stop the spinner from opening because it does not depend on click event.You have to use `android:enabled="false"`

**EDIT**
You can set this in the Java code itself, instead of in the XML, because the Spinner should implement setEnabled(boolean) from View

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  I did not use "enabled" because Android Studio's intellisense does not have "enabled" as a choice.  Anyway, I added that per your suggestion, but the list still shows.  I will edit the question to add the Java code using the spinner.

Comment: yes i also found that issue.You should try setting programatically

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation.  As stated in my original question, it is specifically about this attribute in XML.

Comment: Thank you for trying.  I do not want to waste people's time, so I posted a question as specific as possible without getting into the details of my use scenario. The question is specifically about android:clickable="false".  Any explanation about why it does not work will be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add this android:enabled="false"

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your xml

```
android:enabled="false"
```